# how do i ask user for input of datetime & a variable before plotting

Tags: python

I know how to ask user to input datetime through this code:

this is to make sure the line matches with my text file line which looks something like this

```
TimeStamp, Temperature, Humidity 
DD/MM/YYYY H:M, 10.0, 20.0
DD/MM/YYYY H:M, 12.0, 22.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give him a list of variable names, out of which s/he will choose one:

```
variable_name = raw_input('please enter variable name (TimeStamp, Temperature or Humidity):')
```